# Why this specification is not a difference-in-difference?

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I was reading a recent article in my field and one thing was bothering me. 
The article can be find here : https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/smj.3018 and is an econometric paper about corporate social responsibily.

First the authors do a classic OLS regression with time and firm fixed effects :

[image]
CSR contracting, the variable of interest is a dummy variable switching from 0 to 1 when the firm adopts this practice. They cluster se at the industry level.

For me it's look like a classic diff-in-diff specification in panel data with the two fixed effects and the treatment dummy. But at this point, the author don't refer to the DID framework, which doesn't matter anyway.

But further in the article, they do refer to the DID framework for the first equation of their 2sls regression. The equation is :

[image]

The only difference I see is that in the first equation, the dependent variable was continuous and in the second, it's a bernouilli. But I don't get at all why only the second would correspond to a DiD. 
Besides, in foot note, they mention the work of Bertrand, Duflo, and Mullainathan (2004) who recommend to cluster se at the treatment level so here, the firm level. And indeed, that's what they do for this second regression. But still, why not doing the same for the first ?

I'm not trying to say that the authors are doing wrong but I just want to understand the difference and their reasons. It make me wonder if I'm not completely misunderstanding the DiD specification.

Thank you ! (First time on stackexchange, I hope I describe well my question)